# Не возвращает Json?

Tags: android, json

Перестал работать возврат json от сервера. Вот код

```
protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<SendParam>... params)
    {
        String response=" ";
        callBackSendDate.onSend("Идет загрузка...");
        try
        {
            DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();
            //String URL = "http://music.kamnedsoft.kz/api/get_category";
            //он у нас будет посылать post запрос
            HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(URL);
            //будем передавать два параметра
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(params[0].size());

            //передаем параметры из наших текстбоксов
            for(SendParam info : params[0])
            {
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(info.name, info.value));
            }

            //собераем их вместе и посылаем на сервер
            postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));

            //получаем ответ от сервера
            response = hc.execute(postMethod, res);
            return response.toString();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            callBackSendDate.onError("Сервер не доступен");
        }
        return response;
    }
```

В чем прикол, два идентичных проекта, этот код на другом работает и нигде не зачеркнуты методы, а вот в новом, все по перечеркнуто, типо эти методы старые.

Ниже принтскрины.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сравните фалы Gradle.App и Manifest, что скорее всего покажет вам, что вы используете разные по версии тулзовины в этих проектах, а так же целевые платформы и минимальные версии оси.)

Comment: Начиная с определенной версии (не столь важно с какой) зачеркнутые классы и методы считаются устаревшиви (deprecated). Но это не значит, что оны не будут работать. Ищите причину в другом. А именно - подебажьте, локализуйте проблему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DefaultHttpClient` и прочие объявлены `deprecated` начиная с 19 апи. Соответственно если в манифесте или в градле `targetSdk` 18 или ниже то они не будут зачеркнуты.

Более того начиная с апи 21 они вообще убраны из Android SDK.

По поводу того почему не работает - смотрите логи и какой Exception ловится в вашем коде.

Comment: в прикол том что exception никакого нету, возвращает пустую строчку((( хотя проверял, сервер возвращает json

Comment: Код у вас странный. execute() у DefaultHttpClient возвращает тип `HttpResponse` а у вас он почему-то string. Какой код ответа от сервера?

Comment: Ребят, бейте меня ногами(( забыл прописать в манифесте доступ к интернету

Comment: В таком случае должен был вылетать `SecurityException`: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)

Comment: 09-21 13:17:45.221    6730-6744/com.musictext.denis.musictext D/myTag﹕ java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)

Comment: Вы выше писали "в прикол том что exception никакого нету"

Comment: да блин весь день работал, не увидел в логах)

Comment: for(int i=0; i<100; i++){BORSHEVIK.KickInAFace(dudeniska);}